# In Rust, can I instantiate my const array without hard-coding in the values? Compile-time evaluation?

Tags: arrays, rust, constants, compile-time

I'm trying to instantiate an array in Rust.  Here's one way I could do it at runtime:

```rust
let mut t = [0_u32; 65];
for i in 0..t.len() {
    t[i] = ((i as f64).sin().abs() * 2.0_f64.powf(32.0)).floor() as u32;
}
```

However, since I'm never going to change the values of this array and I'm going to use the values a lot, I thought this might be a good opportunity to explore the cool stuff going on with the `const` compile-time evaluation work being done in Rust.  I could make it compute the array at compile time and just store the results in the program data so it's ready to go immediately at runtime.

My first step was to create the constant array.

```rust
const T: [u32; 65] = [0; 65];
```

Well, this is no good.  I've already instantiated it with all zeros.  That's not right.  Next, I thought maybe I should make a constant function that could instantiate the array.

```rust
const fn sine_table() -> [u32; 65] {
    let mut t = [0_u32; 65];
    let mut i = 0;


    loop {
        if i > 65 {
            break;
        }

        // Do the math...
    }

    t
}
```

And here's where I got stuck.  From what I've read, loops inside constant functions are still only on nightly, and I'm trying to stick with stable Rust for the time being to avoid surprises later on.  So, where does this leave me?  What can I do currently in stable and what's coming down the pipeline in nightly, RFCs, etc.?  My next thought was to investigate macros, but I'm not comfortable enough to go down that rabbit hole just yet without knowing if it'll be fruitful.  My ultimate goal is to make this array a constant without having to type in 65 values by hand.

Comment: Have you considered a build script? https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#case-study-code-generation

Comment: Currently you wouldn't even be able to run this in nightly, or any time soon for that matter, [no `f64` functions are `const fn`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html) because [it can vary between platforms](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/why-is-f64-powf-not-a-const-fn/31093/2?u=optimisticpeach). I'd personally include a file of some sort, or maybe make a proc-macro which can accept dynamic expressions and eval them at compile time.

Comment: @OptimisticPeach Could you please give me a small example of a proc-macro that could evaluate dynamic expressions at compile time?

Comment: A build scripts would be dramatically easier than a proc macro for this usecase.

Comment: @loganfsmyth If you want the credit, please add your build script suggestion as an answer. Yours is what I ended up using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cargo supports `build.rs` files that are compiled and run before the overall compilation. For you, the easiest option would be to use this to generate the table that you would like to use.

The Rust docs have an example for [code generation using this method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/build-scripts.html#case-study-code-generation), so if you take your code and use it to generate the array, you should be good to go. You can put `build = "build.rs"` in your `Cargo.toml` and have `build.rs` be:

```
use std::io::{Result, Write};

fn main() -> Result<()> {
  let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap();
  let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("sin_abs_const.rs");
  let mut f = File::create(&dest_path).unwrap();

  write!(f, "const T: [u32; 65] = [\n")?;
  for i in 0..64 {
    write!(f, "  {},\n", ((i as f64).sin().abs() * 2.0_f64.powf(32.0)).floor() as u32)?;
  }
  write!(f, "];\n")?;

  Ok(())
}
```

then you can load that built file.

Answer (score 5):

As of now on Rust Stable, this is not possible to do (you need const fn expressions for this to work at compile time).

But fortunately there's an "in-between" solution for this use case (that I have as well quite frequently), which is the `lazy_static` macro.

Basically it's a lazy-evaluated runtime expression that is computed on first access only.

https://docs.rs/lazy_static/1.4.0/lazy_static/

Your code would look this way using this macro:

```rust
use lazy_static::lazy_static;

const SINE_TABLE_SIZE: usize = 65;
lazy_static! {
    pub static ref SINE_TABLE: [u32; SINE_TABLE_SIZE] = {
        let mut table = [0_u32; SINE_TABLE_SIZE];
        for i in 0..SINE_TABLE_SIZE {
            table[i] = ((i as f64).sin().abs() * 2.0f64.powf(32.)).floor() as u32;
        }

        table
    };
}
```

Rust Playground sample link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=61146c5f7de2c9ee1cbcd724dd1a730f

Disclaimer: I'm not the author of lazy_static nor I am related to them in any way.

Comment: This is a completely reasonable and sensible solution and it's probably what most people want. However, I'm weird and I've chosen not to use any crates in my project so I've chosen the cargo build file feature instead. But I gave you an upvote because your answer is what a sane person should do.

Comment: @dynamitereed Thanks! To be completely honest I've thought about the build.rs solution since I'm an optimization maniac, but for a 65-sized sin table, I thought it was a bit overkill. If your size was way bigger though it would make perfect sense to have it as a build step, to prevent a computation on first access.