# Best way to setup a lookup table for f64

Tags: rust, lookup-tables

I have a function that makes use of ln(i), where i is u32, many times. Inside this function, I have created a vector inside that function that is setup as

```
let mut lns = vec![0.0f64; 2 as usize] ;
for i in 2 ..= max_ln as usize {
    lns.push((i as f64).ln()) ;
}
```

The first two entries are 0.0 so that I don't need to keep calling lns(i-1) when I want ln(i). Anyway, this gets done at the start of every call to my function. I'm just wondering if there is a way to generate this once and reuse it (with the option of pushing extra values if max_ln changes between calls).  The only alternative that I have come up with so far is to do

```
const LNS: [f64; 128] = [0.0f64,
                        0.0f64,
                        0.693147180559945f64,
                        1.09861228866811f64,
                        1.38629436111989f64,
                        1.6094379124341f64,
                        1.79175946922805f64,
```

etc. at the top of the file, but that is not ideal since I need to initialize it with constant values rather than calls to ln().

I have seen similar situations where people make use of Lazy_Static crate, but was hoping for something simpler since the individual values never change.

Thanks

Comment: Think the only thing to do besides hard-coding the values or using lazy evaluation would be to use a `build.rs` file to generate the hard-coded list like in this Q&A: [In Rust, can I instantiate my const array without hard-coding in the values? Compile-time evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59121887/in-rust-can-i-instantiate-my-const-array-without-hard-coding-in-the-values-com)

Comment: https://lib.rs/crates/phf

Answer (score 1):

I ended up following kmdreko's suggestion, but the details weren't immediately clear, so here's what ended up working for me after doing some follow-up reading of the rust documentation once I knew where to look.

In the root directory of the project,

```
//build.rs
use std::io::{Result, Write} ;
use std::path::Path ;
use std::fs::File ;
use std::env ;

const MAX: usize = 128 ;

fn main() -> Result<()> {
    let out_dir = env::var("OUT_DIR").unwrap() ;
    let dest_path = Path::new(&out_dir).join("ln_int_const.rs") ;
    let mut f = File::create(&dest_path).unwrap() ;

    write!(f, "const BIGLNS: [f64; {}] = [\n",MAX+1)? ;
    write!(f, "  0.0f64,\n")? ;
    write!(f, "  0.0f64,\n")? ;
    for i in 2..=MAX {
        write!(f, "  {}f64,\n", (i as f64).ln())? ;
    }
    write!(f, "];\n")? ;

    Ok(())
}
```

Then, in order to get this loaded in, need to add some code to the top of main file:

```
//src/main.rs
...
include!(concat!(env!("OUT_DIR"), "/ln_int_const.rs")) ;

fn main() {
...
```

I hadn't realized how powerful the build.rs file was. Thanks for the tip.